# How can I revert accidentally changed file ownership

Tags: ubuntu, chown

I did `cd /home; sudo chown -R my-user-name: ./` on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
ls -lF /home
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 51 lord lord  4096 Apr 5 10:38 lord/
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Oct 12 2017 lost+found/
```

How can I reverse from this dangerous state without a reinstall?

Comment: Are you the only user on that system?

Comment: What we need here is that program that I have been meaning to write. The one that could be used when you install a new OS, but keep the old `/home` partition. It would parse the `/home` directory to find all first level directories, automatically add new users (you would not want that bit), and chown -R each of those directories (being careful of un-usual ownerships).

Comment: I'm the only user, but is'n dangerous from the networking point?

Comment: Add to the question, the output of `ls -lF /home`. And what networking point?

Comment: total 20
drwxr-xr-x 51 lord lord  4096 Apr  5 10:38 lord/
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Oct 12  2017 lost+found/

Comment: total 20
drwxr-xr-x 51 lord lord  4096 Apr  5 10:38 lord/
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Oct 12  2017 lost+found/

Comment: **Add to the question**, the output of ls -lF /home. And what networking point?

Comment: The "networking point" only matters if you have activated a service that will share the home directories to the network in some way, e.g. a NFS service, Samba, a writeable FTP service, or something similar. And even then, since you effectively took the other users' files for yourself, unless you have told your password to someone else (or have an easily-guessable password), it depends only on how dangerous *you* are!

Comment: **Add to the question**, the output of `ls -lF /home`.

Answer (score 1):

This may help, restoring the ownerships of all users' home directories in `/home`

```
sudo echo chown root:root /home
awk -F: '$6 ~ /\/home\// {print $3,$4,$6}' /etc/passwd |
    while read -r uid gid home
    do
        [ -d "$home" ] && sudo echo chown -R $uid:$gid "$home"
    done
```

Remove both `echo` components when you're sure it's going to do what you expect.

On my system it produced these potential commands

```
chown root:root /home
chown -R 1000:1000 /home/pi
chown -R 1001:1001 /home/roaima
```